# How to integrate mxgraph with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mxgraph, jgraph

I want to integrate Javascript MxGraph-Editor to React js .I have tried many ways.But It's still showing 'variable'(javascript variable ) not defined .Can anyone help me ?

```
GraphEditor.js:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: EditorUi is not defined
    at GraphEditor.graphicEditor (GraphEditor.js:66)
    at GraphEditor.render (GraphEditor.js:138)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14741)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14696)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15644)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19312)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19352)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to integrate mxGraph with react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883403/need-to-integrate-mxgraph-with-react-js)

Comment: Hi @David thanks for the reply , That answer is not working...!

Comment: You can see some examples here https://codesandbox.io/s/r52m86019m ,  https://codesandbox.io/s/zwqr6zpmpx

Comment: The answer might not be working, but that still makes this a duplicate question. There should only be one of each question, answer or not.